# Python Print text after certain number of blank lines

Tags: python, list, text

I have certain text that is in the format such as:

```
    text:aaaaaaa
    text:bbbbbb
    text:cccccc

    text:ddddd
    text:eeeeee

    text:ffffff
```

I would like to print the text at:

```
    text:fffff
```

How can some python code be written that counts the two spaces between the text and prints the text at text:fffff

Comment: Do you mean you want to print `text:ffffff` because there were two blank lines previously?

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> with open("foo.txt") as fin:
...     any(x.isspace() for x in fin) # skip to 1st blank line
...     any(x.isspace() for x in fin) # skip to 2nd blank line
...     next(fin)
... 
True
True
'    text:ffffff\n'
```

To skip past `n` blank lines

```
>>> n = 2
>>> with open("t.txt") as fin:
...     for i in range(n):
...         any(x.isspace() for x in fin)
...     print next(fin)
... 
True
True
    text:ffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this way:

```
mydictonary = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k,v in 
              (item.split(':') for item in s.split(' ')))
```

Here appy this things:

- whitespace remove from each pairs: `(k.strip(), v.strip())`
- split each part into `"<key> ", " <value>"` pairs: `item.split(':')`
- split the string into `"<key> - <value>"` pairs using `s.split(' ')`